# Creating source tarball for rpmbuild

Tags: tar, rpm, rpmbuild

I am new at building rpms. I have my own project which I want to build an rpm for. The issue is that most of the documentation assumes that you already have a tarball of your source. I understand how to construct a tarball, but I guess I don't know if I need to follow any specific structure. What I have right now is a bunch of source files with some configuration files and a Makefile that I want to package as an rpm and have the rpm extract these files into a specific location on the machine.

It seems unclear to me what the "%build and %install" options do and where they are executed. My impression is that they are executed on the machine creating the rpm and they are used to generate any binary files. My impression is that "%pre, %post, %preun, and %postun" are executed on the machine before and after installs and uninstalls.

So I guess there are a few questions buried in this. First, what sort of structure should I follow for tarring up my files? How do I get these files delivered to a certain directory upon installation? My project is not meant to deliver any binaries, but only source and build files.

Thanks for all of the help!

Answer (score 0):

`*.src.rpm`s which `rpmbuild -ba foo.spec` creates are suited for distribution to a limited circle which has intermediate knowledge about rpm.

Target install directory is determined within the `%install` directive (determined at build time).

If your project is meant to deliver the bare source, you either pass a classy tarball with sufficient README instruction, or even better - feed your stuff to version control system (i.e. `git`) and make it online availiable.